# Making unblocking calls in java

Tags: java, multithreading, call, blocking

I am calling an external api to get a report status once my report status is complete then i should proceed ahead to fetch results What I have done so far is added a sleep but its a blocking call and report is taking some half an hour to complete. So I need a way to unblock my next steps. Can anyone suggest me how can i acheive that ?

```
 String reportStatus = client.ReportStatus(jobId).getStatus();
        while(reportStatus != "Completed"){
            int seconds = 5;
            System.out.println("Waiting:" + seconds);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds*5);
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
            reportStatus = client.ReportStatus(jobId).getStatus();

        }
  final FetchReportResult reportValues = client.fetchReport(jobId);
```

Comment: `reportStatus != "Completed"` is wrong, you should use `(!reportStatus.equals("Completed"))` to compare between strings.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine, what kind of unblocking are you talking about? Do you get some event when the report gets finished?

Comment: Yes.. so you can assume that i submit a query and i wait for its staus to change from pending->executing->complete. Once teh query is complete then only i can fetch results of the query from another API. Rather than sleeping for 25 seconds every time.. i want to use threads such that oen thread will read status and another will fetch results if the status is complete .. any ideas how can we achieve that ..Do i have to store these status in my local database and have two threads reading the values

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for asynchronous calls, you should look into calling this function on a separate thread. You can do this by creating a thread pool, and telling it to execute this code for you. The code will then run in the background, until it is finished, in which case, you can do something with it. Then the only thing you have to do is wrap it in a Runnable, and synchronize with the EventQueue at the end and you're set.

Code to execute:

```
CallBackFunction aFunction = null;
Runnable runnable = new MyRunnable(aFunction);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
executorService.execute( runnable );
```

CallBackFunction interface:

```
public interface CallBackFunction {
  /**
   * Function that gets called when callback is finished
   */
  void callbackfinished();
}
```

And the runnable:

```
   public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

      private CallBackFunction fCallbackFunction;

      public MyRunnable( CallBackFunction callbackFunction ) {
        fCallbackFunction = callbackFunction;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {

        //execute your polling code here//

        if(complete){
          EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              fCallbackFunction.callbackfinished();
            }
          } );
       }
      }
    }
```

When you execute the MyRunnable object, it will not block the running thread. Instead, it will run on a backgroundthread. The runnable will "poll" the server, like you describe in your code. Finally, when the polling is complete, it will call the CallBackFunction to notify that there is a change in completeness.

I hope this helps.

P.S.: I run the callbackfunction on the eventqueue. This might be necessary for your application, but if you're doing GUI stuff, this might be safer.

Comment: I've added some example code. Don't hesitate to ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this operation in another thread, then you will be able to make it as asynchronus call

Answer (score 0):

use an ExecutorService to perform asynchronous calls and thus request are finished by the thread pool in the executor.Check java.util.concurrent.Executors ,it contains some thread pools. Yet,it is a problem that when to close the thread pool to make sure all accepted request are finish when application exit